# Spark executor OOM while joining very small dataset (non-zero exit code 143)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing left outer join on a small data set(total 41 mb). My executor memory is 10GB. When i am not using any in memory persistence on executor the job works fine. But when i use Cache() or persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK()) the job consistently fails with below exception (but works when i use persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY()))

```
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill 42447"...
23/06/14 19:38:57 WARN TaskMemoryManager: Failed to allocate a page (64102862 bytes), try again.
23/06/14 19:38:57 INFO TaskMemoryManager: Memory used in task 4
23/06/14 19:38:57 INFO TaskMemoryManager: 64102862 bytes of memory were used by task 4 but are not associated with specific consumers
23/06/14 19:38:57 INFO TaskMemoryManager: 5500051918 bytes of memory are used for execution and 38002226 bytes of memory are used for storage
23/06/14 19:38:57 WARN BlockManager: Block rdd_27_0 could not be removed as it was not found on disk or in memory
```

and executor is killed with

```
Diagnostics: [2023-05-28 16:24:44.080]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143\n[2023-05-28 16:24:44.080]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143.
```

Below is the screenshot when job works fine.
[image]
Below is the screenshot when job fails
[image]
below is the screenshot for storage
[image]

code

```
Dataset<Row> currentDataSet = hdfsHandler.loadDataSet(sparkSession, "somelocation");
currentDataSet.createOrReplaceTempView(CURRENT_USER_VIEW);
currentDataSet.cache() //<- this causes the issue
Dataset<Row> previousDataSet = hdfsHandler.loadDataSet(sparkSession, "somelocation2);
previousDataSet.createOrReplaceTempView(PREVIOUS_USER_VIEW);
previousDataSet.cache() //<- this causes the issue

String currentRunColumn = "c.".concat("userid");
String previousRunColumn = "p.".concat("userid");

Dataset<Row> addedRecordDataSets = sparkSession.sql("SELECT " + currentRunColumn + " FROM " +
        CURRENT_USER_VIEW + " AS c " +
        " LEFT JOIN " + PREVIOUS_USER_VIEW + " AS p " +
        " ON " + currentRunColumn + " == " + previousRunColumn +
        " WHERE " + previousRunColumn + " IS NULL ");

dataSet.coalesce(1).persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY()).foreachPartition(persist());
```

As par my understanding of above logs, at the time of exception execution memory is around 5gb and while it is trying to get more allocation it fails and the task fails. But can someone please help me understand how 41mb data can result into 5gb of execution memory? Is there a way to estimate the memory required for execution? I have gone through [this](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Spark-Memory-Management/ta-p/317794) and [this](https://0x0fff.com/spark-memory-management/) amazing resources.

**Update**
Even though the data size is very small, peak execution memory is 48.1 GB. But the job does not die even when executor size is only 3gb. but when i add inmemory cache even though very small, the job dies with OOM (even when executor size is 10gb, hence execution size ~5gb), i am suspecting some bug wrt evicting cache?  i am using 2.4.x of spark.

Comment: How many cores per executor do you have ?
Can you also add the storage view so that we see what's going on with cached datagrames memory?

Comment: thanks for suggestion, there are 2 rdds being cached, total size being 81mb. This is the only job running during that period on cluster, so there are no other variables in the system.

Comment: There is 1 core par executor. only 1 job is running in the cluster at that point of time.

Comment: Can you share the code or th physical plan of the result dataframe ? Having a small dataframe as an input doesn't guarantee that it will not grow because of joins for example.

Comment: @AbdennacerLachiheb i have updated the question. even though input data is small <1gb, execution memory goes upto 48gb. I don't face the issue when there is no cache (even if i set the executor memory to 3gb!!), i am suspecting some bug wrt evicting cache in 2.4 version of spark?

Comment: Maybe because you cache at the wrong time, did you try to cache just before the write or in the middle of your code? Again we need some code to invistigate the issue.

Comment: @AbdennacerLachiheb i have added the code as well, if i change .cache to .persist(disk_only()) i don't face any issue.

Comment: How did you know about the execution memory up to 48g ?

Comment: it gets reported on spark ui. beside i found few cases where oom was happening even when execution memory was in 3-4 gb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the issue in our case was using .cache(), when i changed the .cache to .persist(Disk) or removed it all together, i did not face the issue.

Upon digging deeper this issues seems to be related to

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21492

So

a. updating to spark 2.4.5 or 3.0.0 could fix the issue.

b. remove .cache() on dataset.

**UPDATE**

i checked in spark 3.1.5, and no longer seeing the issue.